# Getting an exception while running xamarin forms maps

Tags: xamarin.forms

uncaught exception : API key not found. Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbHiX.png)

Answer (score 4):

> To use the Google Maps functionality in Android, you need to register for a Maps API key with Google. Until you do this, you will just see a blank grid instead of a map in your applications. You must obtain a Google Maps Android API v2 key - keys from the older Google Maps Android API key v1 will not work.
>   Obtaining a Maps API v2 key involves the following steps:

- Retrieve the SHA-1 fingerprint of the keystore that is used to sign the application.
- Create a project in the Google APIs console.
- Obtaining the API key.

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows

**Adding the Key to Your Project**

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows#adding-the-key-to-your-project

Comment: I refer above link only .but i got exception.uncaught exception : API key not found. Check that is in the element of AndroidManifest.xml while map loading

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project and ensure that the generated manifest contains the key in the correct location: (obj/{Release|Debug}/android/AndroidManifest.xml And then delete and re-deploy to your device.

Comment: Clear bin,obj then clean build run

Comment: i am done again i got same exception.anybody know that issues